# Iterating over images doesnt work, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have this code and it works giving me the url of the images in the console.

but it doesn't print out images on my site

```
for (let i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        let url = data[i].token_uri
        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data['image']));

          
           
        let row = `<tr>
                    <td>${data[i].token_id}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].contract_type}</td>
                    <td><h4>${data[i].token_address}</h4></td>
                    <td><img src=${data['image']}></td>
                    
                </tr>`
                
    table.innerHTML += row

}
```

I also tried
let images = data['image']

and than use the images variable in my row

here is the full code, maybe this helps someone to give me a correct answer

```
async function populate(){
    const nft = await



Moralis.Web3API.account.getNFTs({chain: 'matic'}).then(buildTableNFT);
    

}

function buildTableNFT(_data){
    let data = _data.result;
    document.getElementById("resultNFT").innerHTML = `<table class="table table-dark table-striped" id="nftTable">
                                                            </table>`;
    const table = document.getElementById("nftTable");
    const rowHeader = `<thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Type</th>
                                <th>Contract</th>
                                <th>Image</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>`
    table.innerHTML += rowHeader;
    for (let i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        let url = data[i].token_uri
        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data['image']));
        let images = data['image']
          
           
        let row = `<tr>
                        <td>${data[i].token_id}</td>
                        <td>${data[i].contract_type}</td>
                        <td><h4>${data[i].token_address}</h4></td>
                        <td><img src="${images}"></td>
                        
                    </tr>`
                    
        table.innerHTML += row
    
}
```

}

Comment: all you're doing with the JSON response is logging it - how do you expect it to magic its way from `console.log(data['image']` to `src=${data['image']}` - the `data` variable isn't even the same thing ... and lets not forget asynchrony of `fetch`

Comment: so what's the solution

Comment: use async/await

Comment: at least post the code

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch all the data parallel and then build the html. It will be much faster.

```
function buildTableNFT(_data){
    let data = _data.result;

    const promises = data.map(({ token_uri }) => fetch(token_uri).then(res => res.json()));

    Promise.all(promises).then(images => {
        document.getElementById("resultNFT").innerHTML = `<table class="table table-dark table-striped" id="nftTable">
                                                            </table>`;
        const table = document.getElementById("nftTable");
        const rowHeader = `<thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Type</th>
                                    <th>Contract</th>
                                    <th>Image</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>`
        table.innerHTML += rowHeader;
        for (let i=0; i < data.length; i++){            
            let row = `<tr>
                            <td>${data[i].token_id}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].contract_type}</td>
                            <td><h4>${data[i].token_address}</h4></td>
                            <td><img src="${images[i]['image']}"></td>
                            
                        </tr>`
                        
            table.innerHTML += row
        }
    });
    
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work either

Comment: did you get all data? try console.log(data) just before for loop

Comment: your solution isn't working, post the correct code

Comment: You can try my updated code

Comment: it's not working

Comment: I can console log the image but it's not showing up on the ui

Comment: I was referring to your updated code, I can consolelog the url, but it's not showing up

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you use async/await with your code

```
async function populate(){
    const nft = await Moralis.Web3API.account.getNFTs({chain: 'matic'});
    return buildTableNFT(nft);
}

async function buildTableNFT({result}) {
    document.getElementById("resultNFT").innerHTML = `
        <table class="table table-dark table-striped" id="nftTable">
        </table>
    `;
    const table = document.getElementById("nftTable");
    const rowHeader = `
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Contract</th>
                <th>Image</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    `;
    table.innerHTML += rowHeader;
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        let url = result[i].token_uri;
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        const image = data.image;
        const row = `
            <tr>
                <td>${result[i].token_id}</td>
                <td>${result[i].contract_type}</td>
                <td><h4>${result[i].token_address}</h4></td>
                <td><img src="${image}"></td>
            </tr>
        `;
        table.innerHTML += row;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok but it's not working

Comment: actually it is working

Answer (score -1):

The concern is that your ${data['image']} is not accessible outside the context of the .then() promise.

```js
for (let i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        let url = data[i].token_uri
        
        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(item=> {
        
          let row = `<tr>
                    <td>${data[i].token_id}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].contract_type}</td>
                    <td><h4>${data[i].token_address}</h4></td>
                    <td><img src=${item['image']}></td>
                    
                </tr>`
                table.innerHTML += row
        });
}
```

Comment: not working, data[i] is undefined

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have edited it. You can try it. I had used the parameter name "data" in the promise callback yet it was already being used up. 
I have renamed parameter "data" to item

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).